# CSS File not responding

Tags: html, css

The third link in the below code is supposed to be my own stylesheet for a django app I'm creating. There is only one style sheet in the entire application, but for some reason when I went to add new styles today none of them were taking place.

I deleted all the CSS from the file to see if it impacted the site, and it had no effect. Then I deleted the file all together, and still no change in appearance.

Then I commented out the `<link />` to the stylesheet and the website loses its styles! I assume one of two things is happening

1. I'm editing the wrong stylesheet
2. Something is messed up with the browser. However, as I mentioned, this is the only stylesheet in the entire app directory, so I don't know how there could be another style sheet that the link is referring to. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```html
<head>
  {% load static %}
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.6.3/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  <link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href= "{% static 'polls/stylesheet.css' %}" /> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'polls/script.js' %}"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: When working with CSS, make sure to always test after clearing the cache in your browser, or simply run the browser in private mode for caching to be disabled.

Comment: Does indeed sound like a caching issue! Chrome developer tools has a sweet option to always skip the cache when you've got dev tools open! Not sure if you're using chrome.

Comment: Edit your link this way:  `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/polls/stylesheet.css' %}" />` - just in case. Save it and open your page in a private/incognito mode.